# Constructor of objects in heap array

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, constructor

So, I have an object with a constructor. This object doesn't support empty constructors because there are constants that must be assigned in the constructor. Something like this:

```cpp
class Object {
public:
    const int foo;

    Object(int f) : foo(f) {
        // other stuff
    }
}
```

Now I have another function that keeps a dynamically allocated array of objects.

```cpp
Object* objects;
```

I need to be able to allocate this memory using `new[]` and `delete[]` but also use the constructor. I can't seem to figure out how to do this.

Something like this would be ideal

```cpp
objects = new Object[numObjects];
for (int i = 0; i < numObjects; ++i) {
    object[i](foos[i]);
}
```

I could use `malloc` and `free`, then `new` the objects in place, but that would be non ideal as I would have to loop through the objects in the destructor and manually destruct them, then free the memory. Seems messy.

Comment: Try making your constants static.

Comment: Use `std::vector` and you will be able to do that.

Comment: @Gardener The constants differ between objects.

Comment: @Phil1970 I'm trying to keep implementation tight, fast, and low-memory.

Answer (score 1):

You could use list initialisation:

```
objects = new Object[3]{1, 2, 3};
```

But this only works with a constant size array.

> I could use malloc and free, then new the objects in place

This is indeed exactly the way to create an array of dynamic length containing objects of a non-default-constructible type. Except instead of `malloc`, it would be more idiomatic to allocate an array of `std::byte` with `new[]`. This is also how to allocate an array of certain number of objects that you would like to create later.

But there's no need to write that yourself, since the standard library provides you with `std::vector`, which does this for you:

```
std::vector<Object> mycars(numObjects, Object(42));
```

Comment: I don't want to use std::vector in the interest of speed and memory. I might go with malloc. Perhaps I'll do some bench-testing with both implementations and see what I get. Thanks!